# When does heroku app start working after an H12 error?

Tags: heroku

When I encounter an `H12` error on a rails app, if I `heroku restart` it's back up and running right away.

When (if ever) would the app start working again without `heroku restart`? (e.g. do heroku apps automatically restart themselves periodically, or does memory clear itself periodically, or something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An H12 error means the request took longer than 30 seconds to be processed. This is not necessarily a sign of a memory issue.

Your ruby app can only process a finite number of requests at the same time. That's the number of threads * the number of processes your web server (unicorn or puma) is starting.

When you have long-running requests, due to a file upload, calling an underlying API or a slow SQL query for example, that request takes one of those finite slots.
If you have too many of those, any new incoming request will have to wait until one slot of available.

When Heroku kills an HTTP request which takes longer than 30 seconds, it cannot tell your app can the request needs to be cancelled.
So if you have a long request queue, you could end up in a state where all requests end up in H12s even before they start being processed by the app.

Restarting the app fixes it, as it clears the request queue.

The best way to solve this issue is to use a gem like [rack-timeout](https://github.com/sharpstone/rack-timeout) which will kill any request taking longer than the time you set.
A reasonable value would be around 1 or 2 seconds.

See this timeouts documentation from the Heroku Devcenter: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Note that the same issue can happen with your database if you have long-running SQL queries.
Setting a statement timeout on SQL queries is therefore a good thing to do too: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-database-tuning#identify-and-fix-expensive-queries